# How to show incremented Django model field value in template correctly?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have a post model and try to achieve properly views counter but this method not work correctly in template when I try to display views counter in a template.

```
    class Post(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=160)
    slug = models.SlugField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=160)
    content = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now, blank=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='news/photos/', default='', blank=True)
    views = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Post'
        verbose_name_plural = 'News'
        ordering = ['id']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        return super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def count_views(self):
        self.views = F('views') + 1
        self.save()


class PostDetail(DetailView):
model = Post
template_name = 'news/detail.html'

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(PostDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    self.object.count_views()
    context['latest_news'] = Post.objects.all().order_by('-created')[0:10]
    return context

<span><i class="icon-eye icons"></i> {{ post.views }}</span>
```

There may be another method to solve this issue, more correct. Can i solve this with .update queryset?

Comment: What does the template show for the views counter?

Comment: F(views) + Value(1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you using an `F` expression to increment the views counter, but the object has to be reloaded in order for it to pick up the new value. You can use `refresh_from_db()` for this.

```
def count_views(self):
    self.views = F('views') + 1
    self.save()
    self.refresh_from_db()
```

Without reloading, the value of `self.views` will be the  string representation of the `F()` expression, which is what you're currently seeing in the template.